# iOS Dynamic label width according to number of Chars

Tags: ios, swift

I want to Achieve this in the simplest way "Preferably using Storyboard"

[image: I want the Gender Label to be always next to the label]

I want the Gender Image to be always next to the Pet Type label, to achieve this, the label width must be dynamic according to the number of characters. I searched & found several solutions that would require tens lines of lines of code which I believe that there must be simpler solutions.

Please keep in mind that I am using constrains & I did try label.sizeToFit() and it didnt work

Thank you

Comment: Is "gender label" the one with male and female signs? Is "the label" the one with "Pitbull", "Norwegian Forest" etc?

Comment: Yeah Sorry, I meant Gender Image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya Thank you, But my question is how to make a label width Dynamic according to the number of characters in the label

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat refer this link carefully . you can get solution..

Comment: you use autolayout?

Comment: @BrijeshShiroya Yes

Answer (score 2):

That can be done with no code at all.

You've said, you are using constraints, right?

First, you have the image view pinned (presumably, centered vertically and, let's say, 16 to the left (using 'leading' constraint)).

Next, you pin your label (pet label, e.g. "Pitbull") to the image view. That would be its 'leading' constraint. Or you can left-align it with the name label. That makes no difference.

Then, you pin your gender image likewise to the pet label.

Done. When you change the text in the label, everything is recalculated automatically. (Just don't add 'width' constraint to your pet label, and it will adjust depending on the width of the text.)

Comment: So If I don't set a width constrain for the label, It's width will be Dynamic?

Comment: Yes, it will be dynamic

Comment: It worked! Thank you :)  The only drawback is that it leaves me with warnings about not setting the width

Comment: It should not, actually. Can you make screenshot of your constraints and add it here?

Answer (score 0):

User constraints. Give horizontal spacing constraint between label and gender image and animal image. Give width constraint to all the images. That should work.